# Type Id field not getting set while serializing list of polymorphic objects

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Consider this code I wrote to play with Jackson's support for polymorphic serialization/deserialization (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) -

```
public class Main {

    @JsonTypeInfo(
        use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property="type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "dog", value = Dog.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "cat", value = Cat.class)
    })
    public abstract static class Animal {
        public String name;
    }

    public static class Dog extends Animal {
        public int barkLevel;
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal {
        public int meowLevel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String marshalled = "" +
            "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "       \"name\"      : \"cookie\",\n" +
            "       \"type\"      : \"dog\",\n" +
            "       \"barkLevel\" : 5\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "       \"name\"      : \"misty\",\n" +
            "       \"type\"      : \"cat\",\n" +
            "       \"meowLevel\" : 3\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]\n";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        List<Animal> unmarshalledList = mapper.readValue(
            marshalled,
            new TypeReference<List<Animal>>() {}
        );

        Animal[] unmarshalledArray = mapper.readValue(
            marshalled,
            new TypeReference<Animal[]>() {}
        );

        for (Animal animal : unmarshalledList) {
            System.out.println(animal.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        System.out.println(
            mapper.writeValueAsString(
                unmarshalledList
            ) + "\n"
        );

        for (Animal animal : unmarshalledArray) {
            System.out.println(animal.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        System.out.println(
            mapper.writeValueAsString(
                unmarshalledArray
            )
        );
    }
}
```

It produces the following output -

```
Dog
Cat
[ {
  "name" : "cookie",
  "barkLevel" : 5
}, {
  "name" : "misty",
  "meowLevel" : 3
} ]

Dog
Cat
[ {
  "type" : "dog",
  "name" : "cookie",
  "barkLevel" : 5
}, {
  "type" : "cat",
  "name" : "misty",
  "meowLevel" : 3
} ]
```

My question is - when I serialize List<Animal>, no type field is included in the generated json. If however I use Animal[] instead, a type field is included in the generated json. In both cases, the deserialization works fine, ie. the correct subclasses are used. Could someone explain the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serialize a generic collection using polymorphic serialization, you would need to do the following:

```
mapper.writerFor(new TypeReference<List<Animal>>() {}).writeValueAsString(unmarshalledList));
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336) for more details on why this is necessary.